# Information Management Policy Settings Link is Missing in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, information-management, information-policy

I can't find the Information Management Policy Settings anywhere.

I've found a few posts that tell me to first go to Site Collection Features and activate the Library and Folder Based Retention Feature, but it is not there.

I'm trying to get the sharepoint version into word documents and found a good post that explains how to do that http://smackwagondesign.com/how-to-add-the-sharepoint-version-number-to-a-word-document/, but the Information management policy settings link is not there.

Anyone have any ideas how to add the Library and Folder Based Retention Feature?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Foundation, if so that might be the problem. At least in 2010, Information Management was a Standards and up feature (not available in foundation)

Comment: Robert, I'm using 2013.  How do I tell if Foundation is installed?  Thanks.

Comment: http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2013/01/identify-sharepoint-2013-foundation-or.html?m=1 easiest is the comment about central admin